# acts_as_ferret multi model search not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-ferret

I am trying to solve a strange issue with ferret/acts_as_ferret

Of course I have googled and posted the question:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/188570

Basically aaf works on single models with no issue. It also works on single models using the config/aaf.rb file I have setup. It even works when I do a multi-model search in the console, but within the rails app itself I get:

```
undefined method `ferret_rank=' for <object that has a match>
```

If anyone has had the same experience/problem and can shed any light I would appreciate it.

PS: I followed the following tutorial to get where I am now.
http://opensoul.org/2008/4/29/using-shared-indexes-with-acts_as_ferret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the plugin installed or just the gem? You might want to install the plugin.

I would also try rebuilding the index.

For my purposes, I switched to Solr and life is a lot easier. Sphinx is missing a lot of stuff that I need.

Comment: I spoke to Jens the author (who was on vacay - cheers mate) - he mentioned the model was not being extended properly. 

I had it purely in a gem, removed the gem config in envireonment.rb and installed the plugin. 

It works perfectly now.

If anyone still gets this issues also try to require config/aaf.rb in your environment.rb.